# Mixin class issue in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mixins

I am trying to compile this code that was originally written for vs2005 on vs2008. i am getting the errors. Following is the code. Additionally i have these header files providing mixin behavior and they are error free.

Errors:

```
syntax error missing ';' before '<' LINE 86
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default int. LINE 86
'SimpleVehicleMB_1' undeclared identifier LINE 90
'AnnotationMixin' unspecialized class template cannot be used as a tempalte argument for tempalte parameter 'Super', expected a real type. LINE 94
'AnnotationMixin'  use of class template requires template argument list LINE 94
'SteerLibraryMixin' use of claas template requires template argument list LINE 101
```

```
#ifndef OPENSTEER_SIMPLEVEHICLE_MB_H
#define OPENSTEER_SIMPLEVEHICLE_MB_H


#include "AbstractVehicle.h"
#include "SteerLibrary.h"
#include "Annotation.h"


namespace OpenSteer {


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // SimpleVehicle_1 adds concrete LocalSpace methods to AbstractVehicle     LINE 86
    typedef LocalSpaceMixinMB<AbstractVehicle> SimpleVehicleMB_1;


    // SimpleVehicle_2 adds concrete annotation methods to SimpleVehicle_1  LINE 90
    typedef AnnotationMixin<SimpleVehicleMB_1> SimpleVehicleMB_2;


    // SimpleVehicle_3 adds concrete steering methods to SimpleVehicle_2  LINE 94
    typedef SteerLibraryMixin<SimpleVehicleMB_2> SimpleVehicleMB_3;


    // SimpleVehicle adds concrete vehicle methods to SimpleVehicle_3
    class SimpleVehicleMB : public SimpleVehicleMB_3

   {

        public:

            // constructor LINE 101 is the '{' above
            SimpleVehicleMB ();

            // destructor
            ~SimpleVehicleMB ();

            // reset memory backend
            static void resetBackend()
            {
                MemoryBackend::reset();
            }

            // reset vehicle state
            void reset (void)
            {
                // reset LocalSpace state
                resetLocalSpace ();

                // reset SteerLibraryMixin state
                // (XXX this seems really fragile, needs to be redesigned XXX)
                SimpleVehicleMB_3::reset ();

                setMass (1);          // mass (defaults to 1 so acceleration=force)
                setSpeed (0);         // speed along Forward direction.

                setRadius (0.5f);     // size of bounding sphere

                setMaxForce (0.1f);   // steering force is clipped to this magnitude
                setMaxSpeed (1.0f);   // velocity is clipped to this magnitude

                // reset bookkeeping to do running averages of these quanities
                resetSmoothedAcceleration ();
            }

            // get/set mass
            float mass (void) const {return mb->mass(mb_id);}
            float setMass (float m) {return mb->setMass(mb_id, m);}

            // get velocity of vehicle
            Vec3 velocity (void) const {return forward() * speed();}

            // get/set speed of vehicle  (may be faster than taking mag of velocity)
            float speed (void) const {return mb->speed(mb_id);}
            float setSpeed (float s) {return mb->setSpeed(mb_id, s);}

            // size of bounding sphere, for obstacle avoidance, etc.
            float radius (void) const {return mb->radius(mb_id);}
            float setRadius (float m) {return mb->setRadius(mb_id, m);}

            // get/set maxForce
            float maxForce (void) const {return mb->maxForce(mb_id);}
            float setMaxForce (float mf) {return mb->setMaxForce(mb_id, mf);}

            // get/set maxSpeed
            float maxSpeed (void) const {return mb->maxSpeed(mb_id);}
            float setMaxSpeed (float ms) {return mb->setMaxSpeed(mb_id, ms);}


            // apply a given steering force to our momentum,
            // adjusting our orientation to maintain velocity-alignment.
            void applySteeringForce (const Vec3& force, const float deltaTime);

            // the default version: keep FORWARD parallel to velocity, change
            // UP as little as possible.
            virtual void regenerateLocalSpace (const Vec3& newVelocity,
                                               const float elapsedTime);

            // alternate version: keep FORWARD parallel to velocity, adjust UP
            // according to a no-basis-in-reality "banking" behavior, something
            // like what birds and airplanes do.  (XXX experimental cwr 6-5-03)
            void regenerateLocalSpaceForBanking (const Vec3& newVelocity,
                                                 const float elapsedTime);

            // adjust the steering force passed to applySteeringForce.
            // allows a specific vehicle class to redefine this adjustment.
            // default is to disallow backward-facing steering at low speed.
            // xxx experimental 8-20-02
            virtual Vec3 adjustRawSteeringForce (const Vec3& force,
                                                 const float deltaTime);

            // apply a given braking force (for a given dt) to our momentum.
            // xxx experimental 9-6-02
            void applyBrakingForce (const float rate, const float deltaTime);

            // predict position of this vehicle at some time in the future
            // (assumes velocity remains constant)
            Vec3 predictFuturePosition (const float predictionTime) const;

            Vec3 smoothedAcceleration (void) {return mb->smoothedAcceleration(mb_id);}
            Vec3 resetSmoothedAcceleration (const Vec3& value = Vec3::zero)
            {
                mb->setSmoothedAcceleration(mb_id, value);
                return value;
            }

            // give each vehicle a unique number
            int serialNumber;
            static int serialNumberCounter;

            // draw lines from vehicle's position showing its velocity and acceleration
            void annotationVelocityAcceleration (float maxLengthA, float maxLengthV);
            void annotationVelocityAcceleration (float maxLength)
            {annotationVelocityAcceleration (maxLength, maxLength);}
            void annotationVelocityAcceleration (void)
            {annotationVelocityAcceleration (3, 3);}

            // set a random "2D" heading: set local Up to global Y, then effectively
            // rotate about it by a random angle (pick random forward, derive side).
            void randomizeHeadingOnXZPlane (void)
            {
                setUp (Vec3::up);
                setForward (RandomUnitVectorOnXZPlane ());
                setSide (localRotateForwardToSide (forward()));
            }
        };


} // namespace OpenSteer


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif // OPENSTEER_SIMPLEVEHICLE_MB_H
```

Comment: Tell us which line get which error.

Comment: added the line numbers in comments. thanku

Answer (score 1):

Your error message (as posted when I'm writing this) says

> syntax error missing ';' before '<'

In the code you're presenting the first '<' is in this line:

```
typedef LocalSpaceMixinMB<AbstractVehicle> SimpleVehicleMB_1;
```

That this line is where the problem *manifests itself* is borne out by subsequent messages complaining about `SimpleVehicleMB_1`.

So evidently the template and/or the type is not defined at this point.

With the information provided as I'm writing this, most likely it's the template `LocalSpaceMixinMB` that's not defined. Like, you have forgotten to include the relevant header. It could alternatively be that it's the header `"AbstractVehicle.h"` that has a problem.

But you're not showing the relevant code so the only thing to add (for now) is, keep in mind that an error's cause is either at the point where the error manifests itself, or somewhere earlier in the preprocessed source code of the translation unit, e.g. in an earlier included header.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: hi thanks for your response. i have posted another question thats more focused. could you please have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7858555/954974